# Java Date.toString in Oracle's TO_DATE

Tags: java, string, oracle, date

The default format for Date.toString() seems to be, in an US locale, something like:

```
Thu Nov 24 15:20:52 CET 2016
```

Oracle database has a function "TO_DATE" that allows convert from string to date. First argument is the date format.

Which is the correct date format to map a Java Date.toString() string? Is it:

```
DAY MONTH DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: When you access a database from Java, you need to use the `set/getTimestamp` (or `set/getDate`) methods of JDBC, not set string values.

Comment: Live is not always perfect :-). I've no control over the java code nor the value passed, just I can configure the oracle "to_date" format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Oracle `DATE` data type does not have a time zone - you need a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` data type:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
         'Thu Nov 24 15:20:52 CET 2016',
         'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY'
       )
FROM DUAL
```

If you want to convert to a `DATE` (and the time zone region is always `CET`) then you can use:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
         'Thu Nov 24 15:20:52 CET 2016',
         'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS "CET" YYYY'
       )
FROM DUAL
```

If you want it as a `DATE` data type and to respect the time zone in the original string then you will need to (1) convert it to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` data type; (2) convert that value to a standardized time zone (UTC is often used for this); then (3) convert that to a date:

```
SELECT CAST(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
           'Thu Nov 24 15:20:52 CET 2016',
           'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY'
         )
         AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
         AS DATE
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which will output the date `2016-11-24 14:20:52` (the UTC representation of the input date).

Comment: Thnaks for the answer. In second example, "CET" can not be TZD ?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Not when you are using `TO_DATE` as `DATE` data types do not have a time zone so it does not understand the `TZD` format mask (you will get an `ORA-01821: date format not recognized` exception).

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Added an edit to standardize the time zone prior to casting it to a date.

Comment: I can't find syntax TO_TIMEZONE_TZ on Google, but GG suggest me  other method TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ. I have tried it with SQL Navigator and it worked. So, can you explain to me syntax TO_TIMEZONE_TZ ?

Comment: @tuyendev Thanks, yes it should be `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` - typing from another system and I mistyped the function name. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, default Date format with toString() method is **EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy**. I don't know why but Oracle doesn't supports parse syntax 'EEE','MMM' and 'zzz' .

Read more : [Table 9-4 Datetime Format Elements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm)