# Oracle TO_DATE format, symbol for "any character"

Tags: oracle, date, parsing, format

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40842098/4886927) the following query is suggested:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
         'Thu Nov 24 15:20:52 CET 2016',
         'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS "CET" YYYY'
       )
FROM DUAL
```

¿ there are some character to be used in the format with the meaning of "any" ? I like replace "CET" in the format string by something like "..." or "###", that is:

```
'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS ... YYYY'
```

One example, ¿ which format will accept all the following date strings :

```
2017-12-31
2017_12_31
2017x12x31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract relevant part by regular expression.

```
select 
TO_DATE(
      regexp_substr('Thu Nov 24 15:20:52 CET 2016', '^.+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
    ||regexp_substr('Thu Nov 24 15:20:52 CET 2016', ' \d{4}$'), 
    'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY')
from dual;
```

or

```
select 
TO_DATE(
   REGEXP_REPLACE('Thu Nov 24 15:20:52 CET 2016', '\w+ (\d{4})$', '\1'),
   'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY')
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using `to_timestamp_tz`:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 'Thu Nov 24 15:20:52 CET 2016' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'Fri Dec 11 23:16:39 PST 2015' str FROM dual)
SELECT str,
       to_timestamp_tz(str, 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english') timestamp_at_orig_tz,
       CAST(to_timestamp_tz(str, 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english') AS DATE) dt,
       CAST(to_timestamp_tz(str, 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english') AT TIME ZONE '-5:00' AS DATE) dt_at_utc_minus_5,
       cast(sys_extract_utc(to_timestamp_tz(str, 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english')) AS DATE) dt_at_utc
FROM   sample_data;

STR                          TIMESTAMP_AT_ORIG_TZ             DT                  DT_AT_UTC_MINUS_5   DT_AT_UTC
---------------------------- -------------------------------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
Thu Nov 24 15:20:52 CET 2016 24-NOV-16 15.20.52.000000000 CET 24/11/2016 15:20:52 24/11/2016 09:20:52 24/11/2016 14:20:52
Fri Dec 11 23:16:39 PST 2015 11-DEC-15 23.16.39.000000000 PST 11/12/2015 23:16:39 12/12/2015 02:16:39 12/12/2015 07:16:39
```

I've given a three different ways of converting the timestamp-as-a-string into a date:

1. Convert the timestamp as is into a date. Note that this will lose any timestamp information you have - useful if you really don't care about timezone information.
2. Convert the timestamp into a specific timezone (in my example, UTC - 5) before converting it into a date.
3. Convert the timestamp into UTC before converting it into a date (you can use the previous method to do this, but sys_extract_utc() is a little more self-explanatory, IMHO, which can only aid readability and maintainability!).

---

With your updated question (which seems to be more around the date part separator, not the timezone), the following should do the trick:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT '2017-12-31' dt_str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT '2017_12_31' dt_str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT '2017x12x31' dt_str FROM dual)
SELECT dt_str,
       to_date(regexp_replace(dt_str,
                              '([[:digit:]]{4}).([[:digit:]]{2}).([[:digit:]]{2})',
                              '\1-\2-\3'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
FROM   sample_data;

DT_STR     DT
---------- ----------
2017-12-31 31/12/2017
2017_12_31 31/12/2017
2017x12x31 31/12/2017
```

Comment: More interested in a general case, not restricted to CET word. Nowadays it is not usual a pattern format that does not allow a symbol for "any". Someone suggested "#" but my test rejects it.

Comment: Mine is generalised, though? I have two rows in the subquery providing sample data for the query to work on, one of which is CET, the other PST. The query works regardless.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, by example, to accept three strings like "2017-12-01" or "2017_12_01" or "2017x12x01". I will add a clarification to the question.

Comment: Note, `TZR` means "time zone region", there are only limited region names which are working with abbreviation, see `SELECT * FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES WHERE tzabbrev = tzname;`